# Naming a variable with a variable

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on an assignment that uses OOP. The program essentially will create a bunch of different Lemurs based on what the user puts in. They all share similar traits from a Parent class and their own unique traits in their own class.

Part of this program is to allow the user to decide the number of objects (or lemurs) to be created. I want to create objects in a progressive manner, so L1, L2, L3... etc.

Here's what I have so far. So I basically wanted to use the lemCounter to keep track of the Lemur number and attach that to the object name, every time a new object is created.

```
//Main section of code

static int numLems, typeLems, loop, lemCounter;
static String allLems[];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Ask for the number of lemurs
    askNL();
    //Initalize the length of the array to the total number of lemurs
    allLems = new String[numLems];
    //Ask which lemurs the user wants to generate
    //Set the lemur counter and the lemur string to nothing
    lemCounter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numLems; i++){
        //Run the method that asks which lemur they want
        askTL();
        //Run the method to check which lemur the user wanted
        checkTL();
        //Use lemCounter to keep track of the lemur number
        lemCounter++;
    }
}


//Method asking how many lemurs, for the sake of cleaniness in the main method

static int askNL(){
    do{
        try{
            String numLemsStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many Lemurs would you like to generate?");
            numLems = Integer.parseInt(numLemsStr);
            loop = 2;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not an acceptable input, please try again.");
            loop = 1;
        }
    }while(loop==1);
    return numLems;
}

//Method asking which type of Lemur

static int askTL(){
    do{
        try{
            String typeLemsStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What type of Lemur would you like for Lemur "+ lemCounter+1
                    + "\n1 - Tree Lemur"
                    + "\n2 - Desert Lemur"
                    + "\n3 - Jungle Lemur");
            typeLems = Integer.parseInt(typeLemsStr);
            if(typeLems > 3){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not an acceptable input, please try again.");
                loop = 1;
            }
            else{
                loop = 2;
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not an acceptable input, please try again.");
            loop = 1;
        }
    }while(loop==1);
    return typeLems;
}

//Method to decide which lemur the user wanted
static String[] checkTL(){
    if(typeLems==1){
//I'm not sure what I need to put in the name to get it to proceed linearly
        TreeLemur L = new TreeLemur();
    }
    return allLems;
}
```

Comment: -1 for failing to clearly state a question.

Comment: You can't create variables with calculated names. Instead, you should use an array or ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse variable *name* which exists but isn't nearly as important as you'd think with object "name" which doesn't exist. For instance, say you could give a variable name based on a number and had:

```
Lemur lemur1 = new Lemur();
Lemur lemur2 = lemur1;
```

Then what is the "name" of the Lemur object being "named" here? lemur1 or lemur2? Note that they both refer to the the *same* Lemur object.

Use an array or `ArrayList<Lemur>` if you want a sequential collection of Lemurs that can be accessed by number. Use a `Map<String, LemurL>` if you want to have a Lemur associated with a String.

Comment: Interesting part is that OP (kinda) has such array - `allLems`